# Dynamic library: exporting functions that are never referenced inside the library

Tags: c++, linux, macos, shared-libraries

I'm having trouble building a dynamic library on Mac / Linux. If there are functions / methods that are not referenced from within the library (only intended for use by the library's client), such functions are stripped from the library when .dylib / .so is created. Is there a way of dealing with this issue, other than calling such functions within the library to avoid this optimization?

Comment: Please provide a MWE of this behavior, along with the command you are using to build it?

Comment: Read [Drepper's paper: *How to Write a Shared Library*](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) then consider using [visibility](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility) attribute in your code.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: adding `__attribute__ ((visibility ("default")))` helped. How could it be that some (only some) of my library's functions got hidden visibility? I certainly never specified this attribute anywhere.